# Adding a message to Google Group via API

Tags: google-admin-sdk

I am trying to use the Google Groups Migration API to add an entry to a Google Group. According to the documentation I use this url:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/upload/groups/v1/groups/transend@googlegroups.com/archive?uploadType=media
```

I am supplying the auth token correctly I believe (got past http 401 error). Now I am getting http 500, internal server error. The json
response says "Backend Error".  My http headers are:

```
Content-Length: 225
Content-Type: message/rfc822
```

The data that follows is as plain a rfc822 type message as I can make:

```
From: jmckay9351@gmail.com
To: transend@googlegroups.com
Subject: forward test
MIME-Version: 1.0
Date: Mon, 22 Feb 2016 08:03:00 -0800
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="UTF-8"

This is the first line of the message.
```

I believe the group is set up correctly - it can receive messages via email from jmckay9351@gmail.com, just not via the API.  Any suggestions for me?

Answer (score 1):

The Groups Migration API can only be used with Google Apps accounts, not for googlegroups.com.

See [Prerequisites](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/groups-migration/v1/guides/prerequisites):

> Have a Google account and create an administrator. The API applies to Google Apps for Business, Education, Government, Reseller, and ISP accounts.